# I can't make SORT with multiple columns work

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

```
sort -t ';' -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 < unsorted
```

(only column-1 in file 'unsorted' is sorted correct)

```
11;13;08
12;23;24
14;16;15
17;09;04
```

Comment: can you post unsorted as well as the sorted output.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are wrong. `sort` does sort entire lines only. Thus, it will first look at the first column. If there are identical items, these will be sorted according to the second column.

To sort all these columns independently, you may need to first extract the different columns to separate text files, one per column, (`awk` can do that), then have these sorted (`sort`), then recombine these back into one file (`paste`, where the output can be formatted in columns with the `column` command).

Comment: oki, thanks alot! I suspected something like this..I'll look into awk soon